# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.layers.layers' has no attribute 'Layer'

Tags: tensorflow

I'm learning an article called "Attention is all you need", and I'm Trying to learn the code (of the official article from github), and I'm getting weird error, the error is: 
"AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.layers.layers' has no attribute 'Layer'"

The code generating the error:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

import tensorflow as tf
class Attention(tf.layers.Layer)://this is the line the generating the error
```

Now this is weird because when checking online, all the solutions were version problem of tensorflow, and I have a sufficient version (by the answers online) 1.7.0, Also my python version is 3.6.4.

One more thing is it normal that in the error description it's written:"tensorflow.python.layers.layers" and not just "tensorflow.layers"?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1):

So I faced the same error but discovered that my version of **tensorflow** (which 
 is **2.0**) moved layers from the **tf** package (`tf.layers`) to `tf.keras`.

An easy fix would be to replace `tf.layers` with `tf.keras.layers`

Answer (score 0):

From: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/layers/Layer

> tf.layers.Layer is considered legacy, and we recommend the use
>   of tf.keras.layers.Layer instead

After this you may get another error regarding Keras since tensorflow needs to be version > 1.4 so update tf like so:

```
pip install --upgrade tensorflow
```